# How to combine when-then with multi-column conditional computation in Polars

Tags: python-polars

[Modified & extended from another question] My data frame has string columns A, L, G. L & G have a Letter with a 2-digit Number. If the A string is "foo" or "spam", the G string in that row should be changed to it's original Letter + L's original Number, and the L string should be changed to "XX".

```py
df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "A": ["foo", "ham", "spam", "egg",],
        "L": ["A54", "A12", "B84", "C12"],
        "G": ["X34", "C84", "G96", "L60",],
    }
)
print(df)

shape: (4, 3)
┌──────┬─────┬─────┐
│ A    ┆ L   ┆ G   │
│ ---  ┆ --- ┆ --- │
│ str  ┆ str ┆ str │
╞══════╪═════╪═════╡
│ foo  ┆ A54 ┆ X34 │
│ ham  ┆ A12 ┆ C84 │
│ spam ┆ B84 ┆ G96 │
│ egg  ┆ C12 ┆ L60 │
└──────┴─────┴─────┘
```

Expected result:

```
shape: (4, 3)
┌──────┬─────┬─────┐
│ A    ┆ L   ┆ G   │
│ ---  ┆ --- ┆ --- │
│ str  ┆ str ┆ str │
╞══════╪═════╪═════╡
│ foo  ┆ XX  ┆ X54 │
│ ham  ┆ A12 ┆ C84 │
│ spam ┆ XX  ┆ G84 │
│ egg  ┆ C12 ┆ L60 │
└──────┴─────┴─────┘
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your conditional logic is different per column, you'll want to specify the conditionals separately. You can give `df.with_columns` multiple arguments to achieve this.

This solution assumes that the "letter" part is always one character and the "number" is always two characters

```py
import polars as pl
from polars.testing import assert_frame_equal

df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "A": ["foo", "ham", "spam", "egg",],
        "L": ["A54", "A12", "B84", "C12"],
        "G": ["X34", "C84", "G96", "L60",],
    }
)

# factor out the predicate to avoid repeating it 
predicate = pl.when(pl.col("A").is_in(["foo", "spam"]))
result = (
    df.with_columns(
        predicate.then(pl.lit("XX")).otherwise(pl.col("L")).alias("L"),
        predicate.then(
            pl.col("G").str.slice(0, 1) + 
            pl.col("L").str.slice(1, 2)
        ).otherwise(pl.col("G")),
    )
)

# test the result
expected_result = pl.from_repr(
    """
    ┌──────┬─────┬─────┐
    │ A    ┆ L   ┆ G   │
    │ ---  ┆ --- ┆ --- │
    │ str  ┆ str ┆ str │
    ╞══════╪═════╪═════╡
    │ foo  ┆ XX  ┆ X54 │
    │ ham  ┆ A12 ┆ C84 │
    │ spam ┆ XX  ┆ G84 │
    │ egg  ┆ C12 ┆ L60 │
    └──────┴─────┴─────┘
    """
)
assert_frame_equal(result, expected_result)
```

Comment: It appears we posted very similar solutions at the same time! But this is a better solution with reuse of `predicate` and `is_in` instead of `contains`.

Comment: Yes, almost identical! Shows that the polars API really provides "one obvious way" to do things. Thanks @robertdj

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution

```py
(
    df
    .with_columns(
        pl.when(pl.col('A').str.contains('^foo|spam$'))
        .then(pl.col('G').str.slice(0, 1) + pl.col('L').str.slice(1, 2))
        .otherwise(pl.col('G'))
        .alias('G'),

        pl.when(pl.col('A').str.contains('^foo|spam$'))
        .then(pl.lit('XX'))
        .otherwise(pl.col('L'))
        .alias('L'),
    )
)
```